# Adding comments to a bounty

Tags: support, bounty

I offered a bounty for my question. During starting the bounty, it asks me to add some extra comments that what you are looking for. I just select the below option and started the bounty.

> This question has not received enough attention.

Now I want to add some extra comments like "I want the solution for recent release Ubuntu 13.10".

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

From the [help page on bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/bounty):

> **How do I start a bounty? When can I start a bounty?**
>
> A bounty can be started on a question two days after the question was
>   asked.
>
> To start a bounty, click on the "start a bounty" link at the bottom of
>   an eligible question and allocate anywhere between 50 and 500
>   reputation, in 50-point increments. You can also choose from a list of
>   bounty reasons to help other users understand why you’re dissatisfied
>   with any current answers to the question. **If you need to describe
>   something in more detail, there’s also optional, additional custom
>   text that will be displayed with the bounty reason**.

---

If you actually tried starting a bounty, you would get a dialog for entering your custom reason, which is the third and final step when starting a bounty.

[image: Custom dialog]

Comment: i already started a bounty now i want to add some custom message,is that possible?

Comment: Now, that is not possible. You can however add normal comments under the question.